# Is it possible to decrease the font size in the Firefox bookmarks bar?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, bookmarks

I have a lot of bookmarks saved and keep them ordered in folders. However, I feel the font size and spacing in the bookmarks bar is bit large. Therefore, it requires quite a bit of clicking/scrolling to access bookmarks that are hidden by the chevron (>>). Is it possible to minimize the spacing and font for firefox bookmarks bar? That way, it would look nicer similar to Firefox on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox like other Mozilla based UIs (like Komodo) are all controlled by css and unfortunately there's no few button clicks to do this AfAICT.

However, if you're creative you can go nuts see the links [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) and [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration). Otherwise, other people have for you at [usersytles](http://userstyles.org/styles/browse?search_terms=firefox%207).

If you want to go it on your own this and this should help.